# Illustrator - Color settings

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-profile

I played a little bit with the color settings and the working space and I regret it.
Is there a way to go back to the default settings?

Comment: The color settings change to custom when you make adjustments, so can't you just switch back to "North America General Purpose 2" assuming that's the default on your machine? As far as workspaces go you can go to Window -> Workspace and click "Reset" on your current workspace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To reset the workspace:
    - Window / Workspace / Reset (Whichever workspace you had set ie: Essentials)